# Java: Dispose Gui Form

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I'm making a GUI using IntelliJ, and I have selected the option New -> Gui Form. I have made it as a login screen, but I cannot dispose the window at successful login. I have tried to extend the class with `extends JFrame` and then call `dispose()`, but it does not seem to be working. What do I do wrong?

In advance, thank you.

UPDATE with code:

```
public LoginFrame() {
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            char[] pass = password.getPassword();
            StringBuilder passwordBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (char p : pass)
            {
                passwordBuilder.append(p);
            }

            String password = passwordBuilder.toString();

            //Login.
            if(DatabaseHandler.login(username.getText(), password))
            {
                dispose(); //THIS WINDOW.
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Wrong username or password!", "Login failed!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide code. We can't tell you what is wrong if we don't see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Did you try `this.dispose`? And did you check if your code actually enters the `if` block?

Comment: I have tried with dispose, but it fails with this.dispose. The code does enter the if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:

```
        if(DatabaseHandler.login(username.getText(), password))
        {
            Component button = (Component) e.getSource();
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button).dispose();
        }
```

When it does not help, please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand what's wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your class extending JFrame you just use your class name to dispose the JFrame as per the below

```
windowClassName.super.dispose();
```